# Calculate proportion for each category

Tags: r

I have a data frame where I need to add a column, which contain the proportion of bad clients (var Class=bad) for each category of purpose.

this is my data frame (sample)

```
    ClientID             purpose class
1    1215693            radio/tv   bad
2    1215696            used car  good
3    1215699            radio/tv  good
4    1215702            radio/tv  good
5    1215705            radio/tv  good
6    1215708             repairs  good
7    1215711            radio/tv  good
8    1215714             new car  good
9    1215717  domestic appliance  good
10   1215720 furniture/equipment   bad
```

How may I do this?

Comment: Do you need `ave(df$class, df$purpose, FUN = function(x) sum(x=="bad")/length(x))` ?

Comment: can you explain this code please, this could be the answer but I don't understand the "x" I just tried and I've N/A everywhere on my df

Comment: that must be because your `purpose` and `class` columns must be factors. Try convert them to characters first by doing `df[2:3] <- lapply(df[2:3], as.character)` and then apply the above code. As far as `x` is concerned it is a variable that as a parameter in the anonymous function call the way we pass it in a function. Here it represents the `class` column. Check `?ave` for more information.

Comment: I think prop.table() does the trick

Comment: thank you Ronah but look at this error (data_credit_reduce[2:3] <- lapply(data_credit_reduce[2:3], as.character
+ ave(data_credit_reduce$class, data_credit_reduce$purpose, FUN = function(x) sum(x=="bad")/length(x))  Error: unexpected symbol in:
"data_credit_reduce[2:3] <- lapply(data_credit_reduce[2:3], as.character
ave"

Comment: Victor, the prop.table() doesn't run because I don't have only numeric variables

Comment: You need to apply those two commands separately. First run `df[2:3] <- lapply(df[2:3], as.character);` and then `df$newcolumn <- ave(df$class, df$purpose, FUN = function(x) sum(x=="bad")/length(x))`

Comment: thank you Ronah that's work ! Now I just need to group by purpose values